# Como leer datos y almacenar su iformacion en C++?

Tags: c++

Intento reailzar un programa en el cual uno ingrese 3 valores para cada lado de un triangulo, y entonces este decida si es isosceles, escaleno o equilatero.

Apenas empiezo con esto de programacion asi que quisiera saber como debo darle instruccion al controlador para que me almacene los datos del lado a, b y c y luego los lea.

Aqui esta parte del codigo:

```
int a,b,c;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("ingrese valor de a")
  Serial.print("ingrese valor de b")
  Serial.print("ingrese valor de c")
}
void loop()
{  
}
```

Comment: ¿La instrucción `cin` de la librería `iostream` no te sirve?, en tu otro post etiquetas "arduino", supongo a eso te refieres al mencionar "controlador", deberías especificar bien eso, en aquí o en tu otro post, que según veo son iguales.

Comment: listo gracias, pues entonces lo hare, he publicado dos porque no sabia como editar el primer post.